# How can I parse java's version number from "java -version" and assign it to a variable on a remote host?

Tags: java, linux, parsing

I want to fetch the Java version in Linux in a single command then save the output to a variable.

Using the command below assigns the variable to the local version of java. I want to run java -version on the remote host, parse the version number then save the output to a variable.

```
ssh -q -t $server "OLDJAVA=`java -version 2>&1 | cut -s -d '"' -f2`"
```

Comment: You can try reversing the quotes but the variable will get lost as soon as the ssh session finishes. `ssh -q -t $server 'OLDJAVA=$(java -version 2>&1 | cut -s -d "\"" -f2)'`

Comment: which doesn't work for me

Comment: Try to explain in the question what are you trying to do with that variable. Setting it as is is not very useful at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the command on the remote host and set a local variable to the output, which ssh will forward:

```
OLDJAVA=$(ssh -q $server "java -version 2>&1 | cut -s -d '\"' -f2")
```

The `'\"'` responds to the need to send an escaped quote to the remote server. (I missed this on the first iteration.) However, it is easier to do the redirection and post-processing on the local machine, since `ssh` will pass both stdout and stderr back. This results in the somewhat simpler

```
OLDJAVA=$(ssh -q $server java -version 2>&1 | cut -s -d \" -f2)
```

In both cases, I removed the `-t` option because it doesn't seem to be needed. It's possible that the `-q` option will create more problems than it solves (since you will definitely want to react to an ssh error.)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Comment: @jdoe08: Sorry. I missed the need to escape the quote passed  through to the remove shell. Double escaping is always a pain. Now that I have a machine in front of me, I tested the updated line and it seems to work as expected.